# What's the order of usage of Header Tags?

Tags: html

can we use h2 tag before h1,likewise h4 before h3 tag? is it appropriate?

```
 <body>
   <div class="">
      <h2>content</h2>
   <div>

 <div class="">
    <h1>content</h1>
 </div>
 </body>
```

Comment: Order or position doesn't matter. Only some tags are restricted like `<tr>` should be inside `<table>` etc....

Comment: These tags are formatting ones (just like CSS), their numbers follow a logical rule because each one is supposed to indent more. Following the order is just a matter of lisibility.

Comment: Be careful you're not doing this: http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/F43.html (see Failure Example 2).

Answer (score 0):

There is no order to how you use header tags, however, there is a validation rule that a heading cannot be a child of another heading. Please use the [W3C Validator](https://validator.w3.org/) to validate your html.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is appropriate.

Also as a side note, when search engines read your HTML, they give higher priority to `h1` tag, then `h2` etc. regardless of where your tags are. You can have `h4` before `h1`.